# When SMBIOS has multiple OEM strings, libvirtd reports error

Tags: ubuntu

When SMBIOS has multiple OEM strings, libvirtd reports an error of `unsupported configuration: Host SMBIOS information is not available` after executing `virsh sysinfo`.
My system is `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`, and the linux kernel version is `Linux 6.2.0-34-generic x86_64`