# Ubuntu 22.04.3: error when exec virsh sysinfo command: unsupported configuration: Host SMBIOS information is not available

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-22.04

I installed KVM on Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop on Lenovo ThinkSystem SR550. My command I used to install KVM was:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils virt-manager virtinst
```

After installing finished, I executeed `sudo virsh sysinfo` command on this server, I received:

```bash
root@server8:~# virsh sysinfo
error: failed to get sysinfo
error: unsupported configuration: Host SMBIOS information is not available
```

Following [this page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1882202), I executed these command to check SMBIOS information:

```bash
root@server8:~# dmidecode -q -t 0,1,2,3,4,11,17 | awk -v RS='' '/OEM Strings/'
OEM Strings
    String 1: $MV Min UEFI Version -[TEE136T-2.10]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $BA BIOS AC Module Version -[1.7.32]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $SA SINIT AC Module Version -[1.7.45]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $UC Microcode Version -[0500002C]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $SI Integrated BaseBoard Mgmt Cont 3.08 -[CDI340V]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $ET Embedded Deployment Tool 1.70 -[PDL122H]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $MR MRC Version -[0591.D01]-
OEM Strings
    String 1: $ME ME Firmware Version -[4.1.4.339]-
```

```bash
root@server8:~# dmidecode --dump --oem-string 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
No OEM string number 2
```

```bash
root@server8:~# dmidecode --dump --oem-string count
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I encountered this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.3 installed on a Dell R710 server, I didn't know how to fix them, so I reinstalled OS using Ubuntu 20.04 on this Server and I installed KVM successfully.

Now, I don't want to shirk anymore. I want to install KVM successfully on Ubuntu 22.04.

I found an [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146214/when-smbios-has-multiple-oem-strings-libvirtd-reports-error) that encountered the same problem as mine, but it has no solutions.

I need help. Thanks so much for reading and helping me.